# How do I group by using a column I just created?

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a dataset with a team number and then a time variable that is in the format of YYYY-MM-DD. I would like to summarize counts of observation grouped by year then team number. I was wondering if it is possible in SQL to group by a column that you just created? Code looks something like this.

```
SELECT  YEAR([TIME VARIABLE]) as years,
 [TEAM NUMBER],
COUNT(*)
FROM WEEKLY_WINNERS
GROUP BY years, [TEAM NUMBER];
```

Thanks!

Comment: why do you get an error? and which rdms are you using?

Comment: `GROUP BY YEAR([TIME VARIABLE]), [TEAM NUMBER]` should work. If you absolutely want to use the alias, use the query as a subquery, and you can then group by the alias from the query calling it.

Answer (score -1):

```
with WEEKLY_WINNERS as (select Sysdate-365*2 dd, 1  TEAM from dual 
                     union select Sysdate-365 dd, 2  TEAM from dual
                     union select Sysdate-345 dd, 2  TEAM from dual
                    union  select Sysdate dd, 3  TEAM from dual)
SELECT  trunc(dd,'YEAR') as years ,TEAM,
COUNT(*) FROM WEEKLY_WINNERS
GROUP BY trunc(dd,'YEAR'), TEAM;
```

[Example]
[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcdTF.jpg

It is work for Oracle

Comment: The explanation is missing...